# How do I stream live on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, streaming

YouTube now has live video. How do I set that up for myself? I can't find information about live streaming anywhere.

Comment: Ruben - simpler to mark the newer as a duplicate of the older one.

Comment: @Rory: Age shouldn't matter. The better question with better answers should be the "master".

Comment: If all the answers are obsolete, except the new one, I'd suggest the newer one should be merged with the older

Answer (score 1):

As per the [**YouTube support pages** (dated 7 April 2011)](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=1d4f39c0defa8fcb&hl=en)

> Hello YouTube live streaming partners!
>   As you may have read, we're gradually
>   rolling out our self-service live
>   streaming beta platform to partners
>   with accounts in good standing (no
>   Copyright or Terms of Service
>   strikes). The beta platform enables
>   partners to stream live from their
>   channels at any time and schedule
>   events ahead of time to notify their
>   subscribers.
>
> In order to ensure a great live stream
>   viewing experience, we plan to roll
>   this offering out incrementally over
>   the course of the coming year.  If
>   your account is enabled for live
>   streaming, you’ll see a promotion when
>   you log in and visit your channel
>   page.  We know many of our partners
>   are excited about the possibility of
>   live streaming on YouTube.  If you
>   find you have not been enabled, we
>   welcome your enthusiasm but kindly ask
>   for your patience.  There is no
>   process for requesting live streaming
>   for your account - just make sure that
>   your account is in good standing and
>   that you remain an active uploader who
>   respects YouTube’s community
>   guidelines.  We’re working hard to
>   enable the feature to as many partners
>   as possible over the course of 2011.
>   Thanks in advance for your enthusiasm,
>   understanding, and patience.
>
> For partners who are enabled, please
>   use this forum to post questions and
>   issues you encounter, as well as
>   feature requests for funcitonality
>   you'd like to see in the product. The
>   team will monitor the forum to address
>   issues and solicit your feedback. We
>   also hope that as you become more
>   familiar with the product, you can
>   help each other to solve common
>   problems.
>
> Thanks for participating! We’ll
>   continue to update this forum as new
>   product features are released.

Comment: This answer is obsolete. See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/88110/88163