# How can I stream live video on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-live

Nowadays, I see a lot of users live streaming on YouTube and wanted to try it for myself. However, when I go to my channel I don't see an option for live streaming.

I tried researching how to do this on YouTube and Google, but without luck.

So I was wondering, how can I live stream on YouTube?

I don't have any *pro* account or any of that, but I've watched livestreams from users who I don't think have pro accounts either.

So livestreaming is open for everyone, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this older one: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/14605/7726

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was also searching for this in vain. But I found out from the youtube blog that the right to livestream is reserved for **"content partners whose accounts are in good standing."** So you need to become a content partner to livestream as of right now. You can sign up to become a content partner at http://www.youtube.com/yt/creators/partner.html

To answer your question **"So it is open for everyone?"**, **No.** *It is not open to the public yet.* They are beta testing with their content partners.

Source:
http://youtube-global.blogspot.com/2011/04/youtube-is-going-live.html

Comment: This answer is obsolete. See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/88110/88163

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

Go to [Live Streamming](https://www.youtube.com/live_dashboard) or to [Live Events](https://www.youtube.com/my_live_events). From those web pages Youtube creators could check what they need to start live streaming and to schedule live streaming events.

## Extendend answer

The Youtube Creator Blog announced in December 2013 that now "all" channels could do live streaming.

From [Now you can live stream on YouTube](http://youtubecreator.blogspot.mx/2013/12/now-you-can-live-stream-on-youtube.html)

> Now, all YouTube channels that
> [verify](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171664?hl=en) their
> account and are in [good
> standing](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2797387?hl=en)
> will be able to live stream live video to the world. We’re rolling out
> the feature over the next few weeks, and you can see if you have
> access on the YouTube [account feature
> page](https://www.youtube.com/features) or wait for Live Events to
> appear in your [Video Manager](https://www.youtube.com/my_videos).
>
> To give you even more ways to connect with fans, you can now launch a
> Google+ Hangout on Air directly from the [YouTube Live events
> manager](http://www.youtube.com/my_live_events). This gives you a
> simple way to reach your fans live and is the ideal way to to invite
> participants to join your show.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can stream any video on YouTube, you first need to apply for their partnership program.

Although, first read all the requirements that you need for the YouTube partnership program since otherwise you can easily get rejected.

Once you are a partner you can benefit of putting ads on your video which you make money through, also you will be eligible to the live streaming program :) Here is their partner ship page: [Partnership program](http://www.youtube.com/yt/creators/partner.html)

Comment: This no longer seems to be true, not all accounts that are monetized can stream

Comment: This answer is obsolete. See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/88110/88163

Answer (score -3):

You can live stream without being a YouTube partner all you have to do is use a Google Hangout.