# Can I live stream using YouTube Hangouts On Air without using my Google+ account name?

Tags: youtube, google-plus, video-streaming, hangouts-on-air

I noticed YouTube offers live streaming now, via "Hangouts On Air". However it appears to tie to my Google+ account, which uses my real name. I'd rather keep using my YouTube channel only.

[image: screen shot]

I'd like to be able to live stream on YouTube without exposing my Google+ name/credentials, if possible.

Is there a way to do that with Hangouts On Air or is the Google+ bit required?

If making a Google+ "page" is an option then that's acceptable to me but I don't know if I can connect the Hangouts On Air feature to a Page instead of my personal Google+ account as my YouTube account is using the same Google account as my "real" Google+.

Yes I have read [How can I stream live video on YouTube?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27069/how-can-i-stream-live-video-on-youtube) and [How do I stream live on YouTube?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14605/how-do-i-stream-live-on-youtube) but those questions don't apply to the Hangouts stream feature.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Now Youtube offers more options for live streaming. You could still use Hangouts on Air but also could use the [Stream Now [BETA]](https://www.youtube.com/live_dashboard), but if you still want to use Hangouts on Air, you will require a Google+ profile or Google+ page.

## Extended answer

Hangouts on Air requires a Google+ profile or Google+ page connected to a Youtube Channel. It's worth to say that

1. Now are other options for live streaming from a Youtube channel.
2. Youtube is making changes so will not be required anymore a Google+ profile or page to be tied to a Youtube channel.

Regarding 1, now there are three types of doing live streaming in Youtube: Stream now Beta, Quick and Custom Live Event.

Regarding 2, from [Your channel and Google+ - Youtube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2663685?hl=en)

> Most people don't need Google+ to use YouTube.
>
> If you’re comfortable using the [name and photo you’ve
>   selected](https://aboutme.google.com/) for your Google account on
>   YouTube, you no longer need to have a Google+ profile on your account.
>   You can create a channel and use all YouTube features without Google+.
>   If you already have a Google+ profile, it won't affect your channel
>   whether you keep or [remove your Google+
>   profile](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657970).
>
> ### Reasons you might still need Google+ connected to your YouTube channel
>
> - If you want to use a different name and photo on YouTube than the name and photo you’ve chosen for your Google account, your channel
>     should be connected to a Google+ page. When connected to a Google+
>     page, your YouTube channel gets its name and channel icon from the
>     connected page, instead of from your Google account. Any [name and
>     photo changes](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657964) will
>     apply to both the Google+ page and the YouTube channel.
> - If you want multiple managers to have access to your channel without sharing passwords, you can use admin features with a Google+
>     page.
>
> > You’ll soon be able to do the above without Google+ Pages as well.
> >     Check out our [blog
> >     post](https://youtube-global.blogspot.com/2015/07/youtube-comments.html)
> >     for more information and keep an eye on this article for updates.
>
> ### Comment notifications
>
> If you want to get comment notifications through the notification bell
>   , your account needs to have an associated Google+ profile or page.
>
> ### What if I never connected my channel to Google+?
>
> If you’d like to use the same name and photo that you’ve selected for
>   your Google account on YouTube, consider [confirming your
>   name](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657961) so you can
>   regain some features on YouTube, like commenting.

## References

- [Now you can live stream on YouTube - Youtube Creators Blog](http://youtubecreator.blogspot.com/2013/12/now-you-can-live-stream-on-youtube.html)
- [Get started with Hangouts On Air - Classic Google+ Help](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2553119?hl=en)
- [Introduction to Live Streaming - Youtube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2474026?hl=en)
- [Stream now Beta, Quick and Custom Live Event Types](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853848?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your Google+ Profile must be tied to a YouTube page in order for a Google+ Hangout on Air to be streamed live.

You cannot (yet) tie a Google+ Page to a YouTube account, although YouTube has indicated this will be coming "soon", they have not provided further details on doing so.

Comment: This answer is obsolete. See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/88113/88163